# Open Workbook and Store NamedRange Value to a Variable

Tags: excel, vba

MyNamedRange is a **Named Range** in the Sheet **Field Inspection Report**
I want to store value in the Named Range to the variable Var_MyNamedRange.

Error is with the last line. "Object does not support the property method"

```
Dim Export_wb As Workbook 
Dim Var_MyNamedRange As Range
FileSelected = "C:\Users\abc.xlsm"
Set Export_wb = Application.Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileSelected) 
Set Var_MyNamedRange = Export_wb.Range("MyNamedRange")
```

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: Try `Set Var_MyNamedRange = Export_wb.Sheets("Field Inspection Report").Range("MyNamedRange")`

Comment: Adding Sheet name as Siddharth Rout mentioned worked. Thanks!